# Delete Multiple Selected Records from checkbox in a relation

Tags: cakephp

I have two Model. One is user and onother is UserProfile and in created their tables users and user_profiles respectivly. I want when i delete user data thenrelated UserProfile should also automatically deleted. I created hasone and belongs to relation. One more thing i am deleting data using checkbox with delete button so i could able to delete multiple record at once.

## User.php

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'UserProfile' => array(
        'className' => 'UserProfile',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```

## UserProfile.php

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

In UsersController i have a deleteSelected function

## UsersController.php

```
public function deleteSelected()
{
    foreach($this->data['User'] as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value != 0)
        {
            $this->User->delete($value);
        }
    }
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

finaaly i am getting an Error: Table groups_users for model GroupsUser was not found in datasource default. Please tell whats wrong in my code. Thanks.

Comment: why `'dependent' => false`? the meaning of dependant is to obtain what you are requesting

Comment: Also that error doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you are showing here. Please add relevant code regarding group associations if you need help with it. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Thanks!!  Arilia for reply. My cakephp version is 2.4. I have 3 more table. users_type, groups and users_group. My group table has user_id and users_group has user_id and group_id.

Comment: users_group should be groups_users if you are using habtm relationship,

Comment: i got the solution. Actually in User Model i did not follow the proper way for hasbtm with group. I used "public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Group');" but now i bake my User model again and  it is working properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**set dependent to true**

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'UserProfile' => array(
        'className' => 'UserProfile',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```